# Apache CXF upgrade issue

Tags: java, spring, web-services, cxf

I updated cxf to the latest 3.1.4 release and my rest requests are not working anymore since then. (a few other libs were also updated around the same time, so it could be non cxf related)

Here is what I get when I try to access my webapp :

```
17:00:47,251  WARN org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.() - Attention: Elément inconnu deferred-value dans l'attribute
17:00:47,252  WARN org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.() - Attention: Elément inconnu deferred-value dans l'attribute
17:00:47,252  WARN org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.() - Attention: Elément inconnu deferred-value dans l'attribute
17:00:50,550  WARN org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.() - /factory/rest/app/init
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.alinto.server.interceptors.FormatInterceptor.execute(FormatInterceptor.java:45) ~[classes/:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_65]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[?:1.8.0_65]
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270) ~[springloaded-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:621) ~[spring-aop-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:610) ~[spring-aop-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:68) ~[spring-aop-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:653) ~[spring-aop-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at com.alinto.application.rest.ApplicationREST$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$153da2c2.getApplicationInitBean(<generated>) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_65]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[?:1.8.0_65]
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270) ~[springloaded-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:180) ~[cxf-core-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96) ~[cxf-core-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:200) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:99) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59) ~[cxf-core-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:96) ~[cxf-core-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308) ~[cxf-core-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121) ~[cxf-core-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:251) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:180) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at com.alinto.server.CXFServletAdapter.invoke(CXFServletAdapter.java) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:293) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at com.alinto.server.CXFServletAdapter.handleRequest(CXFServletAdapter.java) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doGet(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:217) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at com.alinto.server.CXFServletAdapter.doGet(CXFServletAdapter.java:43) ~[classes/:?]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668) ~[javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:268) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at com.alinto.server.CXFServletAdapter.service(CXFServletAdapter.java) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:684) ~[jetty-servlet-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1496) ~[jetty-servlet-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at com.alinto.server.filters.IPFilter.doFilter(IPFilter.java:40) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1484) ~[jetty-servlet-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at com.alinto.server.filters.XForwardedForAsRemoteHostFilter.doFilter(XForwardedForAsRemoteHostFilter.java:128) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1484) ~[jetty-servlet-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:157) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at com.alinto.security.filters.TokenAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(TokenAuthenticationFilter.java:103) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) ~[spring-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) ~[spring-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1484) ~[jetty-servlet-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85) ~[spring-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1484) ~[jetty-servlet-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1476) ~[jetty-servlet-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:501) ~[jetty-servlet-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137) ~[jetty-server-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557) ~[jetty-security-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231) ~[jetty-server-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086) ~[jetty-server-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:429) ~[jetty-servlet-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193) ~[jetty-server-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020) ~[jetty-server-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135) ~[jetty-server-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116) ~[jetty-server-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370) ~[jetty-server-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494) ~[jetty-server-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:971) ~[jetty-server-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1033) ~[jetty-server-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:644) ~[jetty-http-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235) ~[jetty-http-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82) ~[jetty-server-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:696) ~[jetty-io-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:53) ~[jetty-io-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608) ~[jetty-util-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543) ~[jetty-util-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_65]
17:00:50,551  WARN org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.() - /factory/rest/app/logerr
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.alinto.server.interceptors.FormatInterceptor.execute(FormatInterceptor.java:45) ~[classes/:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_65]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[?:1.8.0_65]
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270) ~[springloaded-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:621) ~[spring-aop-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:610) ~[spring-aop-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:68) ~[spring-aop-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:653) ~[spring-aop-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at com.alinto.application.rest.ApplicationREST$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$153da2c2.logUiException(<generated>) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_65]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[?:1.8.0_65]
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270) ~[springloaded-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:180) ~[cxf-core-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96) ~[cxf-core-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:200) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:99) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59) ~[cxf-core-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:96) ~[cxf-core-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308) ~[cxf-core-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121) ~[cxf-core-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:251) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:180) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at com.alinto.server.CXFServletAdapter.invoke(CXFServletAdapter.java) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:293) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at com.alinto.server.CXFServletAdapter.handleRequest(CXFServletAdapter.java) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:212) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at com.alinto.server.CXFServletAdapter.doPost(CXFServletAdapter.java:50) ~[classes/:?]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:688) ~[javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:268) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at com.alinto.server.CXFServletAdapter.service(CXFServletAdapter.java) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:684) ~[jetty-servlet-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1496) ~[jetty-servlet-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at com.alinto.server.filters.IPFilter.doFilter(IPFilter.java:40) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1484) ~[jetty-servlet-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at com.alinto.server.filters.XForwardedForAsRemoteHostFilter.doFilter(XForwardedForAsRemoteHostFilter.java:128) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1484) ~[jetty-servlet-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:157) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at com.alinto.security.filters.TokenAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(TokenAuthenticationFilter.java:103) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) ~[spring-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) ~[spring-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1484) ~[jetty-servlet-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85) ~[spring-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1484) ~[jetty-servlet-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1476) ~[jetty-servlet-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:501) ~[jetty-servlet-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137) ~[jetty-server-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557) ~[jetty-security-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231) ~[jetty-server-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086) ~[jetty-server-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:429) ~[jetty-servlet-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193) ~[jetty-server-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020) ~[jetty-server-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135) ~[jetty-server-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116) ~[jetty-server-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370) ~[jetty-server-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494) ~[jetty-server-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:982) ~[jetty-server-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1043) ~[jetty-server-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:865) ~[jetty-http-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:240) ~[jetty-http-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82) ~[jetty-server-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:696) ~[jetty-io-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:53) ~[jetty-io-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608) ~[jetty-util-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543) ~[jetty-util-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_65]
17:00:50,584  WARN org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound.() - Request method 'POST' not supported
```

Comment: I see jetty-servlet-8.1.16...Are you still using Jetty 8 perhaps? I think it may not be compatible

Comment: Yes we are still using jetty 8, our prod still runs tomcat 7 so we need to have the same level of supported functionnality. Is there any information about cxf not supporting jetty 8 ?

Comment: What Java version you running? For CXF >= 3.0 you need JDK7. https://cxf.apache.org/faq.html#FAQ-CanCXFrunwithJDK1.7/Java7? and Jetty 8 runs on Java 6 https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Starting/Jetty_Version_Comparison_Table

Comment: We use JDK 7 so this must not be an issue